# How can I count the number of times different terms occur in a string string with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a list of 20 phrases that I want to count in an article.

Currently, I'm doing

```
      let counts = phrases.map((phrase, idx) => {
        phrase.usage = (articleBody.match(new RegExp(phrase.phrase, 'gi')) || []).length
        return phrase
      })
```

This requires me to do an expensive search each time. Is there some way to do it faster or all at once?

Comment: Can the phrases overlap, and do you need to count each of the overlapping occurrences?

Comment: If not, you can turn `phrases` into a single regexp that matches all of them: `var pattern = new RegExp(phrases.join('|'))`

Comment: What do you mean by overlap?

Comment: Can you have phrases `foo bar` and `foo`, and you need to count both of them?

Comment: Yes - we want to count `foo bar` once and `foo` once

Comment: Then you need to do a seprate count for each phrase.

Comment: "*This requires me to do an expensive search each time*" - searching 20 times should not be considered "expensive". How large is your `articleBody`, and how slow is your function? Do you really have performance problems with this script?

Comment: `articleBody` is 2000-3000 words

Comment: Try to move it to a Web Workers - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers.

Comment: You can try to remove from articleBody all the words which are not contained in the phrases first. It could make search faster in case a length of the articleBody is huge.

Comment: I just tested `split` method of string.It takes atleast 50% less time than regex.
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nd19p2xu/2/)

Comment: I just widely updated my answer to better fit your situation, I hope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried it on a 50KB article body and benchmarked it with your usage. The results showing the solution below is %40 faster than your solution.

The benchmark link https://jsben.ch/wWW6e

I decreased the article size for saving it you can increase it for better results.

```
let phrases = [{ phrase: 'placerat', usage: 0 }, { phrase: 'lorem', usage: 0 }];
let matching = article.match(new RegExp(phrases.map(phrase => phrase.phrase).join('|'), 'gi')).reduce((acc, match) => {
    match = match.toLowerCase();
    if (acc[match]) {
        acc[match].count++;
    } else {
        acc[match] = { count: 0 };
    }      

    return acc;
}, {});
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use [`String.prototype.matchAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll)

```js
const str = ['ocurrence 1, and..', 'ocurrence 2, and..', 'other phrases'];

const array = [...str.join ` `.matchAll(new RegExp('ocurrence', 'gi'))];

console.log(array.length); // 2
```

Edit: counting occurrences in one string;

```js
const articleBody = 'ocurrence 1, and.. ocurrence 2, and... etc';
const array = [...articleBody.matchAll(new RegExp('ocurrence', 'gi'))];

console.log(array.length) // 2;
```

Edit 2:

Using a service worker

I created a text of 3000 words ("Lorem ipsum" generator).

main.js

```js
if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
         document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
         const phrases = [
            { text: "Lorem ipsum" },
            { text: "elementum mattis" },
          ];
          phrases.map((phrase, index) => {
            const phraseWorker = new Worker("phrase-match-sw.js");

            phraseWorker.onmessage = function (oEvent) {
              const { text, match } = oEvent.data;
              phrases[index] = { text, match };
            };

            phraseWorker.postMessage({
              article:
                "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sapien orci, ligula leo consequat mus tellus elementum mattis lacus maecenas curabitur, ",
              phrase,
            });
          });
        });
      }
```

phrase-match-sw.js

```js
onmessage = function (event) {
  const { article, phrase } = event.data;
  phrase.match = [...article.matchAll(new RegExp(phrase.text,"gi"))].length;
  postMessage(phrase);
};
```

Answer (score 6):

Please take a look this solution.

```js
function occurrences(string, subString, allowOverlapping) {
    string += "";
    subString += "";
    if (subString.length <= 0) return (string.length + 1);

    var n = 0,
        pos = 0,
        step = allowOverlapping ? 1 : subString.length;

    while (true) {
        pos = string.indexOf(subString, pos);
        if (pos >= 0) {
            ++n;
            pos += step;
        } else break;
    }
    return n;
}

console.time('occurrences');
occurrences("foofoofoo", "bar"); //0
occurrences("foofoofoo", "foo"); //3
occurrences("foofoofoo", "foofoo"); //1
console.timeEnd('occurrences');

console.time('RegExp');
("foofoofoo".match(new RegExp("bar", 'gi')) || []).length; // 0
("foofoofoo".match(new RegExp("foo", 'gi')) || []).length; // 3
("foofoofoo".match(new RegExp("foofoo", 'gi')) || []).length; // 1
console.timeEnd('RegExp');
```

This is the benchmark result: https://jsben.ch/aIqEP

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `|` operator in your `.match()` call to match multiple phrases.  There's an example at [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) for matching fox or cat, but they don't go into the details on counting the results.

But since `match()` returns the results, just build a hash to count the number of times each match occurs...

```js
    // set data we'll be using
var str = "hello 1 hello 2 hello222notarealwordmatch hey 3";       // text string to search
var matchwords = ['hello', 'hey'];    // look for the phrases "hello" or "hey"

    // build regex
var fullmatch = '\\b' + matchwords.join('\\b|\\b') + '\\b';
var match = new RegExp(fullmatch, "gi");     // set "g" for greedy, to search the whole string; "i" for ignore-case, to be case insensitive

    // build match results
var matches = {};
var results = str.match(match);
if(results) {
  results.forEach((thing) => {
    matches[thing] = matches[thing] ? matches[thing] + 1 : 1;
  });
}

    // display results
console.log(matches);
```

In your case, to match exact whole words, you'd also want to match on word borders, for instance `/\bcode\b|\bdatabase\b/` will match `code` and `database`, but not `databaselike` or `codeesque`.  In my example above, you'll see we are searching for "hello", but "hello222notarealwordmatch" correctly gets ignored in the counts.  If you don't care about word-boundaries, then simply remove the 4 instances of `\\b` from up above in defining `fullmatch`...

```
var fullmatch = matchwords.join('|');
```